# I'm trying to get data from flask app but I get this "Uncaught ReferenceError: _data is not defined"

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to get data from flask app but don't know why I'm getting this error "chart-pie-demo.js:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: _data is not defined"
I am creating an inventory app based on flask and sqlite3, I want to add data in a pie graph dynamically so I created a route for this data and referred it to my js file
Here is the code from my chart.js file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   var _data;
   var _labels;
  $.ajax({
   url: "/get_data",
   type: "get",
   data: {vals: ''},
   success: function(response) {
     full_data = JSON.parse(response.payload);
     _data = full_data['data'];
     _labels = full_data['labels'];
   },

 });

});

// Pie Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Orders", "Purchases", "Products"],
    datasets: [{
      data: _data,
      backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf'],
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
    }],
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
      bodyFontColor: "#858796",
      borderColor: '#dddfeb',
      borderWidth: 1,
      xPadding: 15,
      yPadding: 15,
      displayColors: false,
      caretPadding: 10,
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
  },
});
```

Comment: "Each function has its own scope, and any variable declared within that function is only accessible from that function and any nested functions."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the `_data` variable in your `$(document).onReady()` function. That variable will be only available inside it. The code that tries to draw the chart is outside of that function so it cannot access the `_data` variable. Try moving the code that creates the chart inside of your `success` function so that you have the data available and can render the chart immediately.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var _data;
  var _labels;
  var myPieChart;

  $.ajax({
    url     : "/get_data",
    type    : "get",
    data    : {vals: ''},
    success : function(response) {
      full_data = JSON.parse(response.payload);
      _data     = full_data['data'];
      _labels   = full_data['labels'];

      // Pie Chart Example
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");

      myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type : 'doughnut',
        data : {
          labels   : _labels,
          datasets : [{
            data                 : _data,
            backgroundColor      : ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc'],
            hoverBackgroundColor : ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf'],
            hoverBorderColor     : "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
          }]
        },
        options : {
          maintainAspectRatio : false,
          tooltips            : {
            backgroundColor : "rgb(255,255,255)",
            bodyFontColor   : "#858796",
            borderColor     : '#dddfeb',
            borderWidth     : 1,
            xPadding        : 15,
            yPadding        : 15,
            displayColors   : false,
            caretPadding    : 10
          },
          legend : {
            display : false
          },
          cutoutPercentage : 80
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Made my day :)